# How can i create an app from my local system website setup and deploy the files into shopify partner account?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I want to create an app from my local system website setup. But the procedure that I follow is not working properly.
I saw some video tutorials but it did not give needed output. I created four files named : generate_token.php, install.php, api_call_write_products.php, inc folder including one functions.php file. 
I created one private app from the admin site of the partners account but still its not working.How can I upload those files into my partners accounts. Is there any third party tool to upload/deploy those four files including inc folders? How can I integrate my local files into the partners account so that I can see my APP into the partners account. I added the API Keys and Shared_secret key into the files where it was required. I added the files below -

install.php

```
<?php

// Set variables for our request
$shop = $_GET['shop'];
$api_key = "***************";
$scopes = "read_orders,write_products";
$redirect_uri = "https://dd351ab1814cec97dcb5e8d919887c2a:abb65451f1f5c828011242c806971e2b@bahlultechstore.myshopify.com/admin/api/2020-01/orders.json/generate_token.php";

// Build install/approval URL to redirect to
$install_url = "https://" . $shop . ".myshopify.com/admin/oauth/authorize?client_id=" . $api_key . "&scope=" . $scopes . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($redirect_uri);

// Redirect
header("Location: " . $install_url);
die();
```

generate_token.php

```
  <?php

 // Get our helper functions
 require_once("inc/functions.php");

 // Set variables for our request
 $api_key = "**********************";
 $shared_secret = "***********************";
 $params = $_GET; // Retrieve all request parameters
 $hmac = $_GET['hmac']; // Retrieve HMAC request parameter

 $params = array_diff_key($params, array('hmac' => '')); // Remove hmac from params
 ksort($params); // Sort params lexographically

 $computed_hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', http_build_query($params), $shared_secret);

// Use hmac data to check that the response is from Shopify or not
if (hash_equals($hmac, $computed_hmac)) {

// Set variables for our request
$query = array(
    "client_id" => $api_key, // Your API key
    "client_secret" => $shared_secret, // Your app credentials (secret key)
    "code" => $params['code'] // Grab the access key from the URL
);

// Generate access token URL
$access_token_url = "https://" . $params['shop'] . "/admin/oauth/access_token";

// Configure curl client and execute request
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $access_token_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($query));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($query));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// Store the access token
$result = json_decode($result, true);
$access_token = $result['access_token'];

// Show the access token (don't do this in production!)
echo $access_token;

} else {
// Someone is trying to be shady!
die('This request is NOT from Shopify!');
}
```

api_call_write_products.php

```
// Get our helper functions
require_once("inc/functions.php");

// Set variables for our request
$shop = "demo-shop";
$token = "*******************";
$query = array(
    "Content-type" => "application/json" // Tell Shopify that we're expecting a response in JSON format
);

// Run API call to get products
$products = shopify_call($token, $shop, "/admin/products.json", array(), 'GET');

// Convert product JSON information into an array
$products = json_decode($products['response'], TRUE);

// Get the ID of the first product
$product_id = $products['products'][0]['id'];

// Modify product data
$modify_data = array(
    "product" => array(
        "id" => $product_id,
        "title" => "My New Title"
    )
);

// Run API call to modify the product
$modified_product = shopify_call($token, $shop, "/admin/products/" . $product_id . ".json", $modify_data, 'PUT');

// Storage response
$modified_product_response = $modified_product['response'];
```

function.php

```
<?php

function shopify_call($token, $shop, $api_endpoint, $query = array(), $method = 'GET', 
$request_headers = array()) {

// Build URL
$url = "https://" . $shop . ".myshopify.com" . $api_endpoint;
if (!is_null($query) && in_array($method, array('GET',  'DELETE'))) $url = $url . "?" . http_build_query($query);

// Configure cURL
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 3);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
// curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 3);
// curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'My New Shopify App v.1');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);

// Setup headers
$request_headers[] = "";
if (!is_null($token)) $request_headers[] = "X-Shopify-Access-Token: " . $token;
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);

if ($method != 'GET' && in_array($method, array('POST', 'PUT'))) {
    if (is_array($query)) $query = http_build_query($query);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);
}

// Send request to Shopify and capture any errors
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$error_number = curl_errno($curl);
$error_message = curl_error($curl);

// Close cURL to be nice
curl_close($curl);

// Return an error is cURL has a problem
if ($error_number) {
    return $error_message;
} else {

    // No error, return Shopify's response by parsing out the body and the headers
    $response = preg_split("/\r\n\r\n|\n\n|\r\r/", $response, 2);

    // Convert headers into an array
    $headers = array();
    $header_data = explode("\n",$response[0]);
    $headers['status'] = $header_data[0]; // Does not contain a key, have to explicitly set
    array_shift($header_data); // Remove status, we've already set it above
    foreach($header_data as $part) {
        $h = explode(":", $part);
        $headers[trim($h[0])] = trim($h[1]);
    }

    // Return headers and Shopify's response
    return array('headers' => $headers, 'response' => $response[1]);

}

}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused here. You don't upload your app in the App Dashboard, you create API Key and API Password there that you can pass to your code in order to generate access token to the store you are installing the app to it. You upload your app to 3rd party hosting service, Shopify doesn't provide hosting service for apps.

Answer (score 0):

You don't upload your files to Shopify, you host them on your own server.

If you want to test your code locally use ngrok. You can find steps on how to do that [here](https://www.shopify.ca/partners/blog/shopify-admin-authenticate-app).

When you want a prod environment have a look at heroku to host your code.